# Azure VM Site Replication

Tags: backup, azure, virtual-machines, replication, disaster-recovery

I'm looking to set up **site replication for our Azure VM's**. My question is this, h**ow often are the VM's backed up/replicated to the DR site**? Is this **replication automated** or would I need to kick off this process in a *manual* fashion?

Also, is there a difference between setting up site replication in the recovery services vault vs. setting it up by selecting the virtual machine?

As a test I was able to set it up by using both methods but I wasn't sure if one method offered different features or not. I'd appreciate any clarification on this matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once replications is configured the actual replication process is done automatically, this process is continuous as explained [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/azure-to-azure-common-questions):

> Replication is continuous when
>   you're replicating Azure VMs to another Azure region. For more
>   information, see the Azure-to-Azure replication architecture.

Since the replication is continuous, Azure provides you with **crash-consistent** recovery points each 5 minutes. Also, by default there is an **app-consistent** snapshot available each 4 hours, although you can set any value between 1 to 12 hours.

You get the same result setting this up from the VM than doing it from the recovery services vault, the fact that we have the option to do it in both places is only a matter of ease of use.

Comment: Thank you for this info, it was very helpful!